# Hanging Indent on choices within exam document class

Tags: indentation, exam

I've manipulated where I want the initial indents to be for the stem and the choices with a multiple choice test. However, I don't know how to modify the hanging indent on a choice.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{head}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\mdseries



\begin{questions}
%1
\question 
A dose of blah would be likely to produce which of the following blah?\vspace{5mm}
\begin{choices}
\choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\choice sweating 
\end{choices}\vspace{5mm}


\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, the second line of choice D should align with the first. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to update `\itemsep`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
  \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}%
}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  %1
  \question 
  A dose of blah would be likely to produce which of the following blah?\vspace{5mm}
  \begin{choices}
    \choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    \choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    \choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    \choice blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
            blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    \choice sweating 
  \end{choices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```